# Manipulate Data and Format Data

Tags: php, mysql, data-manipulation

I am in need of help. Inside of my table *equipmentCache* I receive data formatted as this:

```
 73688 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6098 0 0 0 52 0 51 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 35 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I need to retrieve each individual code. I need this done in **PHP** because the CMS I am building is straight **PHP** and I rely on it....

> Example: **73688 is a code.** **So is the, "0", right next to it.**

I need to get every single code out, then put that individual code into a link.
Just like this:

```
 <a href="http://www.wowhead.com/item=73688" class="q4">Skyshatter Cover</a>
```

I need this automation because the population of people and each individual character are far too great to do it by hand.

Thank you for your time, and I appreciate any help.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. I would also strongly recommend that you had a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better idea of how SO works.

Comment: "What you've tried" means that you have a problem, it's sufficiently localized so that it can be solved with one function/object/class, you said you've tried things, but where are those attempted solutions? We aren't going to write that class for you, we expect you to show us what you have, and we'll help you from there.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but you could use php's explode function to put it in array and then simply loop through it. You should also trim it, in order to get rid of the "`" character at the beginning and the end of your string...

```
$codes = "`73688 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6098 0 0 0 52 0 51 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 35 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`";
$codesArr = explode(' ', trim($codes, '`'));
foreach($codesArr as $code) {
// generate links... each individual code would be represented by the $code variable..
}
```

Comment: That ` characters is there because someone though it would be cool to edit my post. I tried this solution but it seems as thought when I generate each link it doesn't link to each individual code it, it links as one big code with nothing unchanged. I do appreciate your time and help. :)

Comment: @MichaelToole I think you're doing something wrong. The explode fn should work. Can you post the code you actually used to try this please?

Comment: $codes = $results['equipmentCache'];
$codesArr = explode(' ', trim($codes, '`'));
foreach($codesArr as $code) {
echo "<a href='";
echo $codes;
echo "'>";
echo "sdfkdfsnkdsjfa";
echo "</a>";
}

Comment: @MichaelToole foreach($codesArr as $code) { echo "<a href='"; echo **$codes**; echo "'>"; echo "sdfkdfsnkdsjfa"; echo "</a>"; }

$codes needs to be changed to $code.

Comment: The mistake you made has nothing to do with the complexity of the database, honestly - you just completely failed at basic PHP. We all make mistakes though, so good on you for truckin' on.